# Is it possible to get the diagnostics printed out for a C program in Java?

Tags: java, c, eclipse, compiler-construction, mingw

I want to compile the following C codes from a java program (the syntax errors have been intentionally left):

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World")

}
```

I want my java program to compile the C file and give the diagnostics in the console.
Example: Line 4 ; expected and line 5 invalid syntax...

I have installed the CodeBlock MinGW Compiler and have been able to get the codes compiled and got the errors printed out.

Have a look at what I did:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class C_Compile {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        String ret = compile();
        System.out.println(ret);

    }
    public static String compile()
    {
        String log="";
        String myDirectory = "C:\\";
        try {
            String s= null;
            //change this string to your compilers location
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C gcc hello.c", null, new java.io.File(myDirectory));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            boolean error=false;

            log+="\n....\n";
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                log+=s;
                error=true;
                log+="\n";
            }
            if(error==false) log+="Compilation Successful !!!";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return log;
    }


    public int runProgram()
    {
        int ret = -1;
        try
        {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start a.exe");
            proc.waitFor();
            ret = proc.exitValue();
        } catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
            return ret;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I got the following results:

```
    ....
hello.c: In function 'main':
hello.c:9:1: error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

But I wanted to know if it's possible to get the diagnostic from a listener. I want to get line numbers, positions, types of the syntax errors which will be later input in an array for further processing.

Below is what I wanted to have like in Java:

http://prntscr.com/sgvya

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    List<CaptureErrors> myerrors = new ArrayList<CaptureErrors>();
    MyDiagnosticListener listener = new MyDiagnosticListener(); 
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager  = compiler.getStandardFileManager(listener, null, null); 

    String fileToCompile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\MyC.java";

    Iterable fileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(fileToCompile));  
    CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, listener, null, null, fileObjects); 
    Boolean result = task.call();
    if(result == true){
        System.out.println("Compilation has succeeded");
    }
    myerrors = listener.getlistofErrors();
    for (CaptureErrors e : myerrors)
    {
        System.out.println("Code: " + e.getCode());
        System.out.println("Kind: " + e.getKind());
        System.out.println("Line Number: " + e.getLinenumber());
       // System.out.println("Message: "+ e.getMessage(Locale.ENGLISH));
        //System.out.println("Source: " + e.getSource());
        System.out.println("End position: "+ e.getEndposition());
        System.out.println("Position: "+ e.getPosition());
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
```

Comment: I think you have to parse response from C compiler by yourself to get line numbers and other stuff.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I mean you have a string `log` that contains output from compiler. It string contains information about compilation process and why it failed. You can parse your string and get manually line numbers and other stuff. It's pretty messy but I don't know other way.

Comment: Thanks anyway. And yes it will be a real pain to get the details from the string log. That's why I wanted to know if I could call a listener or something.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `Runtime.exec()` use `ProcessBuilder` and `redirectErrorStream(true)` on it. That way you will be able to capture both **stdout** and **stderr** from compiler output. And instead of invoking via `cmd /c` invoke the **gcc** executable directly from `ProcessBuilder`. Check for `exit code` status from child process. A non 0 exitcode usually means some error in the child process. Then use some regex to extract the error messages and line numbers from the output stream (which would also contain the stderr output of gcc.exe).

Comment: Can you please give me a link where I can all the necessary details?