# How to compile C ar C++ codes in a java program in eclipse and do error logging?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, mingw

I have to develop a program in java which takes a C or C++ file as input and compiles the file and gives the locations, positions, types of the errors found in the program. I am more concerned with the syntax errors. I need a way to do this in eclipse java. I have installed the Eclipse CDT plugin, and I don't know if I can call the compiler from inside a java program and get the line numbers, locations, positions.

I have tried installing a compiler namely the MinGW compiler and been able to print the errors but I am not getting the errors the way I want.
Here's a link of what I tried [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833558/is-it-possible-to-get-the-diagnostics-printed-out-for-a-c-program-in-java)

Can someone help me out to capture the line numbers, positions of the syntax errors found in the C program in an array?

Comment: If you have to write the compiler yourself, the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` approach is not the right direction, then take the time and write a lexical parser, etc. If you can use an external compiler, google one for your platform which produces the expected result.

Comment: No i don't have to write the compiler. I would like to have a compiler which scans my C codes and have a way to capture all the diagnostics. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Please post a sample compiler output, and explain more what you expect.

Comment: There's a link above in my question. I have run the program in the link above and have the MinGW compiler installed. It works fine but I am getting the errors in an inappropriate way. I am just getting the last line number and a bunch of messages. I need to capture the line numbers and positions of each error in the file and input them in an array for later processing. I have asked this question with the hope of having a new way of solving my problem. N.B: Please consult the link. Thanks.

Comment: I could see only 2 lines of sample compiler output there.

Comment: Yes the string log captures the errors as a whole and it is not what i want to achieve. I want a way to capture the line numbers, positions...separately. Any idea of how I can do it?

Comment: I have just seen that you have not accepted any answer for your questions. If you like an answer, you can mark it accepted. That will increase even your points.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the result from the `stdout` and from `stderr`. In the question you linked you can find solutions how to access them.

You also mentioned that you want to have a listener for compiler errors.

```
public interface CompilerErrorListener {
    public void onSyntaxError(String filename, String functionName, 
        int lineNumber, int position, String message);

    public void invalidOutputLine(String line);
}
```

You can implement this with any implementations:

```
public class CompilerErrorProcessor implements CompilerErrorListener {
    public void onSyntaxError(String filename, String functionName, 
        int lineNumber, int position, String message) {
        ....
        // your code here to process the errors, e.g. put them into an ArrayList
    }

    public void invalidOutputLine(String line) {
        // your error handling here
    }
}
```

So, let,s parse the compiler output! (note, that this depends on your compiler output, and you provided only 2 lines of output)

```
BufferedReader stdError = ...
String line;

CompilerErrorListener listener = new CompilerErrorProcessor(...);

String fileName = "";
String functionName = "";
int lineNumber = -1;
int position = -1;
String message = null;

while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    // the line always starts with "filename.c:"
    String[] a1 = line.split(":", 2);
    if (a1.length == 2) {
        // a1[0] is the filename, a1[1] is the rest
        if (! a1[0].equals(fileName)) {
            // on new file
            fileName = a1[0];
            functionName = "";
        }
        // here is the compiler message
        String msg = a1[1];
        if (msg.startsWith("In ")) {
            // "In function 'main':" - we cut the text between '-s
            String[] a2 = msg.split("'");
            if (a2.length == 3) {
                functionName = a2[1];
            } else {
                listener.invalidOutputLine(line);
            }
        } else {
            // "9:1: error: expected ';' before '}' token"
            String[] a2 = msg.split(":", 3);
            if (a2.length == 3) {
                lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(a2[0]);
                position = Integer.parseInt(a2[1]);
                message = a2[2];

                // Notify the listener about the error:
                listener.onSyntaxError(filename, functionName, lineNumber, position, message);
            } else {
                listener.invalidOutputLine(line);
            }
        }

    } else {
        listener.invalidOutputLine(line);
    }

}
```

This is not a complete example, of course, there may be many more possibilities, but hope that you got the idea. Don't forget to log the invalid/unprocessed branches.

Since you use a specific compiler, you have to adapt to its output. Also, changes in the compiler version may result in changes of the parsing code. Take an extra care to discover the structure of the output, it pays when you want to parse it.